# Add Drag and Drop on RecyclerView with DiffUtil

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I have a list that gets updated from a Room Database. I receive the updated data from Room as a new list and I then pass it to [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter)'s `submitList` to get animations for the changes.

```
list.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { updatedList ->
    listAdapter.submitList(updatedList)
})
```

Now, I want to add a drag and drop functionality for the same RecyclerView. I tried to implement it using `ItemTouchHelper`. However, the `notifyItemMoved()` is not working as ListAdapter updates its content through the `submitList()`.

```
override fun onMove(
    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
    target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
): Boolean {

    val from = viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition
    val to = target.bindingAdapterPosition

    val list = itemListAdapter.currentList.toMutableList()
    Collections.swap(list, from, to)

    // does not work for ListAdapter
    // itemListAdapter.notifyItemMoved(from, to)

    itemListAdapter.submitList(list)

    return false
}
```

The drag and drop now works fine but only when dragged slowly, when the dragging gets fast enough, I get different and inconsistent results.

[image: Screen record]

What could be the reason for this? What is the best way that I can achieve a drag and drop functionality for my RecyclerView which uses ListAdapter?

Comment: It's been a while but shouldn't the positions be `adapterPosition` instead of `bindingAdapterPosition` or is that a new thing due to ViewBinding?

Comment: ```adapterPosition``` is now deprecated and replaced with  ```absoluteAdapterPosition``` or  ```bindingAdapterPosition```

Comment: Ahh thanks. I should read the docs more often. I think the issue my be the "time" it takes the collection to be copied (to a mutable list), then the items moved, and finally the submit list needs to use the Diff Util to compute the changes. Most of this is asynchronous so it may be an timing issue. Are you using DiffUtil or AsyncDiffUtil with your list? Can you show your diff Util? How many items do you have? How many calls are you seeing in onItemMoved (while you drag)?

Comment: Yeah, it's probably a time issue. The ```ListAdapter``` uses ```AsyncListDiffer```. My diff util compares id's on```areItemsTheSame``` and then the contents on ```areContentsTheSame```. I even tried to do it without the custom object with many contents and rather only use string but still gets the same issue. The ```onItemMoved``` are called the same amount as the number of position changes when dragged slowly, and inconsistent counts (less than the supposed amount as some are skipped) when dragged quickly.

Comment: (unrelated) but you can save the Collections.Swap call with Kotlin's magic of value capture: `list[from] = list[to].also { list[to] = list[from] }` (though I'd argue this is more obscure for newcomers and basically anyone who reads this code) :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up implementing a new adapter and use it instead of ListAdapter, as mentioned on [Martin Marconcini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68452428/10833325). I added two separate functions. One for receiving updates from Room database (replacement for `submitList` from ListAdapter) and another for every position change from drag

***MyListAdapter.kt***

```
class MyListAdapter(list: ArrayList<Item>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    // save instance instead of creating a new one every submit 
    // list to save some allocation time. Thanks to Martin Marconcini
    private val diffCallback = DiffCallback(list, ArrayList())

    fun submitList(updatedList: List<Item>) {
        diffCallback.newList = updatedList
        val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback)

        list.clear()
        list.addAll(updatedList)
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

    fun itemMoved(from: Int, to: Int) {
        Collections.swap(list, from, to)
        notifyItemMoved(from, to)
    }

}
```

***DiffCallback.kt***

```
class DiffCallback(
    val oldList: List<Item>,
    var newList: List<Item>
) : DiffUtil.Callback() {

    override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
        return oldList.size
    }

    override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
        return newList.size
    }

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        val oldItem = oldList[oldItemPosition]
        val newItem = newList[newItemPosition]
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        val oldItem = oldList[oldItemPosition]
        val newItem = newList[newItemPosition]
        return compareContents(oldItem, newItem)
    }
}
```

**Call `itemMoved` every position change:**

```
override fun onMove(
    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
    target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
): Boolean {
    val from = viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition
    val to = target.bindingAdapterPosition
    itemListAdapter.itemMoved(from, to)

    // Update database as well if needed

    return true
}
```

**When receiving updates from Room database:**

*You may also want to check if currently dragging using [onSelectedChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ItemTouchHelper.Callback#onSelectedChanged(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20int)) if you are also updating your database every position change to prevent unnecessary calls to `submitList`*

```
list.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { updatedList ->
    listAdapter.submitList(updatedList)
})
```

Comment: Good solution; a tiny optimization would be to save the DiffUtilCallback instance and not create a new one when you submit list, since those can be reused. It will save you some allocation time. You can call `DiffUtil.calculateDiff(callback)` any time.

Answer (score 4):

So I made a quick test (this whole thing doesn't fit in a comment so I'm writing an answer)

My Activity contains the adapter, RV, and observes a viewModel. When the ViewModel pushes the initial list from the repo via LiveData, I *save* a local copy of the list in mutable form (just for the purpose of this test) so I can quickly mutate it on the fly.

This is my "onMove" implementation:

```
val from = viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition
val to = target.bindingAdapterPosition

list[from] = list[to].also { list[to] = list[from] }

adapter.submitList(list)
return true
```

I also added this log to verify something:

```
Log.d("###", "onMove from: $from (${list[from].id}) to: $to (${list[to].id})")
```

And I noticed it.. works. But because I'm returning `true` (you seem to be returning false).

Now... **unfortunately**, if you drag fast up and down, this causes the list to eventually become shuffled:

E.g.: Let's suppose there are 10 items from 0-9.

You want to grab item 0 and put it between item 1 and 2.

You start Dragging item 0 at position 0, and move it a bit down so now it's between 1 and 2, the new item position in the `onMove` method is 1 (so far, you're still dragging). Now if you slowly drag further (to position 2), the onMove method is from 1 to 2, NOT from 0 to 2. This is because I returned "true" so every onMove is a "finished operation". This is fine, since the operations are slow and the ListAdapter has time to update and calculate stuff.

But when you drag fast, the operations go out of sync before the adapter has time to catch up.

If you return `false` instead (like you do) then you get various other effects:

- The RecyclerView Animations don't play (while you drag) since the viewHolders haven't been "moved" yet. (you returned false)
- The `onMove` method is then spammed every time you move your finger over a viewHolder, since the framework wants to perform this move again... *but the list is already modified*...

So you'd get something like (similar example above, 10 items, moving the item 0)> let's say each item has an ID that corresponds to its position+1 (in the initial state, so item at position 0 has id 1, item at position 1 has id 2, etc.)

This is what the log shows while I slowly drag item 0 "down":
(format is `from: position(id of item from) to: position(id of item to)

```
onMove from: 0 (1) to: 1 (2) // Initial drag of first item down to 2nd item.
onMove from: 0 (2) to: 1 (1) // now the list is inverted, notice the IDs.
onMove from: 0 (1) to: 1 (2) // Back to square one.
onMove from: 0 (2) to: 1 (1) // and undo-again...
```

I just cut it there, but you can see how it's bouncing all over the place back and forth. I believe this is because you return false *but modify the list* behind the scenes, so it's getting confused. on one side of the equation the "data" says one thing, (and so does the diff util), but on the other, the adapter is oblivious to this change, at least "yet" until the computations are done, which, as you guessed, when you drag super fast, is not enough time.

Unfortunately, I don't have a good answer (today) as to what would the best approach be. Perhaps, not relying on the ListAdapter's behavior and implementing a normal adapter, where you have better list/source control of the data and *when* to call submitList and when to simply notifyItemChanged or moved between two positions may be a better alternative for this use-case.

Apologies for the useless answer.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I tried to implement a new adapter and not rely on the ListAdapter's behavior [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68458012/10833325), and it's working as expected so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried [danartillaga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68458012/1219012) and got a `ConcurrentModificationException` for the `list` variable. I use LiveData in the code and it looks like the data was changed during invalidation of the list.

I've tried to keep the ListAdapter implementation and concluded to the following solution:

```
class MyListAdapter : ListAdapter<Item, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(MyDiffUtil) {

    var modifiableList = mutableListOf<Item>()
        private set

    fun moveItem(from: Int, to: Int) {
        Collections.swap(modifiableList, to, from)
        notifyItemMoved(from, to)
    }

    override fun submitList(list: List<CourseData>?) {
        modifiableList = list.orEmpty().toMutableList()
        super.submitList(modifiableList)
    }
}
```

and the onMove code from `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback`:

```
override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
    val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as CoursesDownloadedAdapter
    val from = viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition
    val to = target.bindingAdapterPosition
    val list = adapter.modifiableList

    // Change your DB here

    adapter.moveItem(from, to)
    return true
}
```

The magic here is saving the `modifiableList` inside the adapter. ListAdapter stores a **link** to the list from `submitList` call, so we can change it externally. During the Drag&Drop the list is changed with `Collections.swap` and RecyclerView is updated with `notifyItemMoved` with no DiffCallback calls. But the data inside ListAdapter was changed and the next `submitList` call will use the updated list to calculate the difference.

Comment: Any idea how to do with Java code?

Comment: It's almost the same

Comment: This works for me as it should, thank you for an idea!
I'm kinda confused why google deliver the library but some things like dragging not working out of the box :(