# Blank space between elements with listAdapter/recyclerview.adapter when removing an item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I have a `ListAdapter` with my `recyclerView` and each element can display his own details in full screen.

In the details screen I have a delete option. This updates a table in my `DB` and I'm retrieving the information with `Flow` and I transform that flow into a `livedata` in the `viewModel`.

When the `recyclerview` tries to update the list, the deleted item is not displayed (as expected), but it also leaves a blank space between elements. I can't figure out how to remove that blank space.

I can drag and drop the items with the top right icon, and after the rearrangement, the adapter recalculates the size/position of each `viewholder` and the blank space disappear.
Also, loading the same `fragment` fixes the issue.

Finally, I tried to move to from `ListAdapter` to `RecyclerView.Adapter` following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68458012/2989467) answer, but the blank space remains.

Any suggestions are welcome.

[image: blank space]

Here are some code snippets:

```
override fun onCreateView(){
    .....
    _binding = FragmentBaseTrackedBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
                .apply {
                    lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
                    list.adapter = trackedItemAdapter
                    .....
    trackedViewModel.listResults.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { trackedItems ->
        trackedItemAdapter?.submitList(trackedItems)
    }

class TrackedViewModel(....){
    val listResults = trackedItemsRepository.getItems()
        .asLiveData(Dispatchers.Default + viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
}

class TrackedItemsRepository(....){
    fun getItems(): Flow<List<TrackedInfo>> {
         return trackedItemsDao.getItemsDao().map{ it ->
             TrackedInfo(.....)
         }
    }

@Dao
interface TrackedItemsDao {
    @Query("SELECT ........")
    fun getItemsDao(): Flow<List<TrackedItemsDao>>


class ItemDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<BaseTrackedInfo>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: BaseTrackedInfo, newItem: BaseTrackedInfo): Boolean =
        oldItem.keyName == newItem.keyName

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: BaseTrackedInfo, newItem: BaseTrackedInfo): Boolean =
        oldItem == newItem
}
```

The adapter code

```
    class TrackedItemAdapter @AssistedInject constructor(
        @Assisted("onItemSelected") private val onItemSelected: (keyName: String) -> Unit,
        @Assisted("itemTouchHelper") private val itemTouchHelper: ItemTouchHelper
    ) : ListAdapter<BaseTrackedInfo, BaseTrackedItemViewHolder>(ItemDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TrackItemViewHolder =
        TrackItemViewHolder(
                ItemTrackedBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    parent,
                    false
                ), .....
            )
        }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseTrackedItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        if (item != null) {
            holder.bind(item)
            holder.dragIcon.setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->
                itemTouchHelper.startDrag(holder)
                return@setOnTouchListener true
            }
        }
    }
```

the viewholders code

```
class TrackItemViewHolder(
    private val binding: ItemTrackedBinding,
    onItemSelected: (keyName: String) -> Unit
) : BaseTrackedItemViewHolder(binding.root) {

override var dragIcon: ImageView = binding.dragIcon

init {
    binding.setClickListener {
        with(binding) {
            item?.let {
                onItemSelected.invoke(it.keyName)
            }
            root.hideKeyboard()
        }
    }
}

override fun bind(itemTracked: BaseTrackedInfo) {
    binding.apply {
        item = itemTracked as TrackedInfo
        executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

the viewholders xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="clickListener"
            type="android.view.View.OnClickListener" />

        <variable
            name="item"
            type="........." />

    </data>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small_100"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_100"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small_100"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_100"
        android:onClick="@{clickListener}">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/picture"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/xlarge_150"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/xlarge_150"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small_100"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_100"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_100"
                android:contentDescription="@{item.displayName}"
                android:imageUrl="@{item.imageUrl}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small_100"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_100"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small_100"
                android:text="@{item.displayName}"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dragIcon"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/picture"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="item_name" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/dragIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_100"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small_100"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_drag_handle" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/levelTitle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small_100"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_100"
                android:text="@string/level_title"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/picture"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/level"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small_100"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_100"
                android:currentLevel="@{item.current}"
                android:desiredLevel="@{item.desired}"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/picture"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/levelTitle"
                tools:text="@string/level_change" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</layout>
```

Comment: Can you post the recycler view adapter's code and item's XML layout?

Comment: @lpizzinidev hi, I updated the question with the code